# Sending formData with axios post request not work properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, form-data

I tried to append form data to fData variable and send it with axios post request to API, but it takes around one to two minutes and responds with error message:

> Request failed with status code 500

I tried to use

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

but nothing has changed in return.

I also tried the same request with Postman and it works just fine with out any latency.

Here is the request sent from Postman:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV4KY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX4d6.jpg

Here is a code sample for axios post request:

```
const AuthToken = `${store().Registration.token_type} ${store().Registration.access_token}`;
const data = {
    governorate: store().Home.governorate,
    supervisor: store().Home.supervisorId,
    name: store().Home.retailerName,
    landline: store().Home.landLine,
    phone: store().Home.phone,
    streetNo: store().Home.streetNo,
    streetName: store().Home.streetName,
    branchedFrom: store().Home.branchedFrom,
    specialMarque: store().Home.specialMarque,
    advertisementType: store().Home.advertisementType,
    competitors: store().Home.competitors,
    license: store().Home.haveLicense,
    currentLocation: store().Home.currentLocation,
    machineInfo: store().Home.machineInfo
}

var fData = new FormData();
fData.append('image1', store().Home.imagesData.image1);
fData.append('image2', store().Home.imagesData.image2);
fData.append('image3', store().Home.imagesData.image3);
fData.append('data', data);

console.log(fData);

axios.post(`http://www.fawryvisibility.com/api/create-retailer`,
fData,
{ 
    headers: { Authorization: AuthToken }
}
)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const {status} = response.data
    if(status == 'Token is Invalid' || status == 'Token is Expired' || status == 'Authorization Token not found'){
        dispatch(logout());
    }
    else if(status == 'freezed'){
        alert('الحساب الشخصي', 'لقد تم إيقاف حسابك الشخصي');  
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('error 3 ' + error);
    dispatch(addValueToStore({
        isSendingAllData: false
    }));
    alert('إرسال البيانات', 'لم يتم إرسال كافة البيانات بنجاح، أعد المحاولة مرة أخرى');
});
```

I expected that the formData would be submitted successfully, I also tried to append images data with null value and sent it back but the same error keeps appear.

Comment: "Request failed with status code 500" — Look at the server-side error logs. Find out what the exception that triggered the 500 response actually is.

Comment: Look at the Console in the developer tools. Are there any *other* error messages? Perhaps some that are CORS related?